# Next13 hydration error when updating html className in <Script/>

Tags: local-storage, tailwind-css, next.js13, hydration

Im using tailwindcss, and would like to set the html className to 'dark'(retrived from localstorage) as soon as possible to reduce flashing when refreshing site.

I was trying to use 'useEffect' as recommended but it's still flashing because the changes are applied after first render on client,
i figured out that i can use  from next/script but with strategy
'afterInteractive' i get still the flashing,
and with
'beforeInteractive' i get hydration error in dev mode(but works excelent when build).
i saw that in next-themes they are setting 'suppressHydrationWarning',
is it not working thought in my case but makes me wonder if its possible to disable hydration warnings on element when you expect it?